# Java_Questions: need help in understanding

Tags: java, hibernate

I appeared for an interview few days back. Some of the questions asked in interview of those i don't know the answer. Can anyone please help me understanding those.

Q1 : Can we catch Errors ? Here answer is Yes we can catch errors. Anything under Throwable class can be caught. but as per the book standard we should the errors but as per the interviewer point of view we should catch so that in any case my application won't show any blank page or Java error to user. So i am able take the gist like whether we need to catch error or not

Q2 : What is the DIALECT property in hibernate configuration file ? I didn't get any significance of this property anywhere.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand question 1.  Regarding question 2, the dialect is the actual SQL flavor your server uses (MySQL, Postgre, Oracle 10, 11, ...)

Comment: 1st Question is Can we catch error in catch block or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You have posted two entirely unrelated questions. I shall answer the first one.

Normal business code should never catch `Error`s, but framework code, which controls the entire request processing lifecycle, definitely *should* catch `Error` exactly as your interviewer explained. You don't want your entire application to go offline due to a single `StackOverflowError` or `OutOfMemoryError`, most of which are fully recoverable from.

Comment: Yes Marco, Both the questions are not related but in interview it was asked in flow :).

Comment: Hi Marko, Is there any specific reason behind Normal Buisness code should never catch Error ? By Doing so, User will never face blank screen. We can provide some meaningful msg to them. Please explain

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the answer: your application contains both "normal business code" and "framework code" in different layers. It is not appropriate to catch Errors in the "normal business code" layer.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I don't understand this question.

Q2: Different databases understand a different SQL. So Oracle's 11g needs different SQL than Microsoft SQL Server 2012.etc

Comment: Hibernate normally autodetects the dialect, that is why OP reports not observing any effect of the setting.

Comment: indeed, being able to configure it is pretty much legacy, I can imagine that even when you have different persistence units mapping to different databases Hibernate can still figure it out. I tend to put it anyway just for documentation purposes.

Comment: i am having one more question on this . . Suppose in Driver property tag i m providing oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver and in Dialect i am using MYSQL Dialect. Then what will happen